# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: x11extras

Tags: linux, qt, pyqt, qt5, qt5.5

I'm trying to build the pyqtdeploy-sysroot containing Qt5 and PyQt5 for the current machine (x86_64 system).
I tried Qt5 versions 5.15.0, 5.15.1 or 5.15.2 on a Fedora 30 (tried 31 and 32 as well as Debian 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, too) system using pyqtdeploy 3.0, 3.1 and 3.1.1.
On all systems I've installed all build dependencies I can think of:

```
python python3 python3-pip libssl-dev zlib1g-dev pyqt5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libgles2-mesa-dev
```

I event tried installing `*x11*-dev` and `*gl*-dev` (`-devel` respectively) :)

I always run into the following problem:

```
Running 'sip-install --qmake /home/frans/_HOME/2011_pyqt/docker_home/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake --no-distinfo --concatenate 2 --no-docstrings --verbose'.
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
/home/frans/_HOME/2011_pyqt/docker_home/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake -query
This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.15.0 (licensed under the GNU General Public License) for Python 3.7.7 on linux.
Found the license file 'pyqt-gpl.sip'.
These bindings will be built: QtCore, QtNetwork, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtX11Extras.
Generating the QtCore bindings...
Generating the QtNetwork bindings...
Generating the QtGui bindings...
Generating the QtWidgets bindings...
Generating the QtX11Extras bindings...
Generating the .pro file for the QtCore module...
Generating the .pro file for the QtNetwork module...
Generating the .pro file for the QtGui module...
Generating the .pro file for the QtWidgets module...
Generating the .pro file for the QtX11Extras module...
Generating the top-level .pro file...
Generating the Makefiles...
/home/frans/_HOME/2011_pyqt/docker_home/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake -recursive PyQt5.pro
sip-install: '/home/frans/_HOME/2011_pyqt/docker_home/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake -recursive PyQt5.pro' failed returning 3
Info: creating stash file /tmp/tmp1_ng3eyh/.qmake.stash
Reading /tmp/tmp1_ng3eyh/QtCore/QtCore.pro
Reading /tmp/tmp1_ng3eyh/QtNetwork/QtNetwork.pro
Reading /tmp/tmp1_ng3eyh/QtGui/QtGui.pro
Reading /tmp/tmp1_ng3eyh/QtWidgets/QtWidgets.pro
Reading /tmp/tmp1_ng3eyh/QtX11Extras/QtX11Extras.pro
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: x11extras
pyqtdeploy-sysroot: execution of 'sip-install' failed: returned exit code 1
```

I'm trying basically the same thing as this guy: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2020-September/043203.html - but it seems like he had given up and switched to iOS..

Any idea what I can do to investigate this behavior? I didn't modify anything regarding pyqtdeploy, Qt5, or the demo, all I'm doing is

```
pip3 install pyqtdeploy sip PyQt-builder
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/8c/1416eaed51c87a5ac934ee982e5c6e0a9dcab8d9b0b0461d4b8b259db5f6/pyqtdeploy-3.1.0.tar.gz
tar xf pyqtdeploy-3.1.0.tar.gz
cd pyqtdeploy-3.1.0/demo
python3 build-demo.py --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

You obviously left some steps out here because in clean installs of Ubutu 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS I can't get far enough into what you did for it to actually attempt to build Qt.[image: python error]

[image: another python error]

[image: yet another python error]

Here is what I can tell you. In a clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM I run this and can build either CopperSpice (a Qt 4.8 fork) or Qt code.

```
#
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev libglib2.0-dev \
            libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libice-dev \
            libaudio-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libc6-dev libsm-dev libxcursor-dev \
            libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev \
            libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxkbcommon-dev \
            libxkbcommon-x11-dev libx11-dev

sudo apt-get install libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-glx0-dev \
            libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev \
            libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-render-util0-dev \
            libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev \
            libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
            libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev

sudo apt-get install g++ gperf ninja-build cmake
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev libasound2-dev libssl-dev libcups2-dev \
            libxml++2.6-dev postgresql-server-dev-10 

sudo apt-get install git

# extra for diamond
sudo apt-get install hunspell libhunspell-dev astyle
```

In a clean Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VM I run this script and can do the same.

```
#
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev libglib2.0-dev \
            libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libice-dev \
            libaudio-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libc6-dev libsm-dev libxcursor-dev \
            libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev \
                    libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxkbcommon-dev \
            libxkbcommon-x11-dev libx11-dev

sudo apt-get install libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-glx0-dev \
            libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev \
            libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-render-util0-dev \
            libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev \
            libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
            libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev

sudo apt-get install g++ gperf ninja-build cmake
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev libasound2-dev libssl-dev libcups2-dev \
            libxml++2.6-dev postgresql-server-dev-12

sudo apt-get install git

# extra for diamond
sudo apt-get install hunspell libhunspell-dev astyle
```

So, what I suggest is that you pick one of your VMs, open a terminal,

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

then run the appropriate script. I suspect you are falling over because of the XCB stuff. It shouldn't take you long to run one of those scripts in the appropriate VM to try this.